# Devise email and password can not be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I have this code in my application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?
before_filter :store_location
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password) }
end
```

but I still have validation errors from devise

```
Email can't be blank
Password can't be blank
Password can't be blank
Role is not included in the list
```

Devise was working fine few days ago I don't know what messed up with it I have added active_admin may be this created conflicts any help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the Problem by adding this line in user.rb

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :role
```

and this works with gem " protected_attributes"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are getting the validation errors while **updating a User record.**

```
def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password) }
    ## Permit the attributes for account_update
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role) }
end
```

You need to permit the attributes explicitly which you would like to be updated by specifying `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)` else they would not be passed to users table for updating.

Comment: yeah true i just add attr_accessible :email, :password, :role in user.rb and everything become fine. Thanks